# .htaccess code mod-rewrite code cleaning

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im kind a new in this mod rewrite thing.

im trying to do some basic redirect.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pickndrive.info
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pickndrive.info/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^new/cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? profiles.php?carname=$2&carnumb=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^used/cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? used.php?carname=$2&carnumb=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? compare.php?car[]=$1&car[]=$2&car[]=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? compare.php?car[]=$1&car[]=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]+)/? compare.php?car[]=$1 [L]
```

thats my  .htaccess but its in a very bad condition !

### what im trying to do is.

1) Trying to tell google that pickndrive.info and www.pickndrive.info are the same.

2) redirect /new(or used)/cars/(INT value)/(string) to X.php?carname=(string)&carnumb=(INT)

**3) redirecting /cars/(STRING) into a search page search.php?query=$1**

**4) redirecting /cars to browse.php?#tabs-all**

5) redirecting compare/*/ (any amount up to 3 times) to compare.php?car[]=X1&car[]=X2&car=X3

well as far is this its working. but i cannt get goal number 3/4 to work cause if i do they just screw the rest :(.

can some one point me out how to write a nice clean .htaccess mod-rewrite please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this for #3/4?

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)/? search.php?query=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cars/? browse.php [L]
```

You should be able to add that at the end. Note that the `#tabs-all` isn't going to translate as a rewrite, since it's something the browser handles on the client side and nothing the server can do. You could maybe add some javascript to automatically get the browser to go to #tabs-all with some javascript in browse.php.

I don't know if there's a cleaner way to do #5 besides the 3 "compare" rules, and #1 and #2 are fine. If you rename (or symlink) "search.php" to "new.php", you could combine those 2 rules to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? $1.php?carname=$3&carnumb=$2 [L]
```

but I think it's better to distinctly rule out /new/cars/ and /used/cars/, since that rule would also rewrite "/qwerty/cars/" to "qwerty.php?..."

Comment: problem is if i did that RewriteRule RewriteRule ^cars/? browse.php [L] or anyother rules based on cars/? it also confuse the images and js files loading from new/cars/qwerty/qwerty .

Comment: The `^` indicates that the expression must match at the beginning. So "^cars/" will never match "new/cars"